# Snake game: snake and apples do not appear on the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make the snake game in python, but sadly my snake and my apples aren't appearing on the screen, all i see is a gray screen with nothing on it, can you help me out? thanks!
P.S - i would like an explanation as well about why my current code isn't working so i would avoid it in the future, thanks again.

```
import pygame, sys, random, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowWidth = 500
windowHeight = 500
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight), 0, 32)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
color = (100, 100, 100)
snakeHead = [250, 250]
snakePosition = [[250, 250],[240, 250],[230, 250]]
applePosition = [random.randrange(1,50)*10,random.randrange(1,50)*10]

def collisionBoundarias(snakeHead):
    if snakeHead[0] >= 500 or snakeHead[0] < 0 or snakeHead[1] >= 500 or snakeHead[1] < 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def collisionSelf(SnakePosition):
    snakeHead = snakePosition[0]
    if snakeHead in snakePosition[1:]:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

while True:
    windowSurface.fill(color)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                snakeHead[0] += 10
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                snakeHead[0] -= 10
            if event.type == pygame.K_UP or event.type == pygame.K_w:
                snakeHead[1] += 10
            if event.type == pygame.K_DOWN or event.type == pygame.K_s:
                snakeHead[1] -= 10

    def displaySnake(snakePosition):
        for position in snakePosition:
            pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface   ,red,pygame.Rect(position[0],position[1],10,10))

    def display_apple(windowSurface, applePosition, apple):
        windowSurface.blit(apple ,(applePosition[0], applePosition[1]))

    snakePosition.insert(0,list(snakeHead))
    snakePosition.pop()


    def displayFinalScore(displayText, finalScore):
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',35)
        TextSurf = largeText.render(displayText, True, (255, 255, 255))
        TextRect = TextSurf.get_rect()
        TextRect.center = ((windowWidth/2),(windowHeight/2))
        windowSurface.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(2)

    def collisionApple(applePosition, score):
        applePosition = [random.randrange(1,50)*10,random.randrange(1,50)*10]
        score += 1
        return applePosition, score

    if snakeHead == applePosition:
        applePosition, score = collisionApple(applePosition, score)
        snakePosition.insert(0,list(snakeHead))


    pygame.display.update()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    clock.tick(20)
```

Comment: That might be because you're never actually drawing your snake? `displaySnake` is never called upon, in fact, most of your functions and stuff is never used. And you'ved defined them in a `while` loop. You never said it, but it's obvious that this is one of your first ever projects. And I don't discourage jumping right into game design, game making etc. But you better make sure you have a damn good teacher who can intuitively describe everything to you. Because there's quite a few mistakes here. If you want to fiddle around with a snake game (part 2 inc because this is getting to long)

Comment: I strongly suggest you take a look at the [pygame examples](https://github.com/ternus/pygame-examples) where they have a [snake game](https://github.com/ternus/pygame-examples/blob/master/snake.py). They've solved it quite differently. You're not far from having a working code yourself. But there's **many** things that needs to be fixed, essentially your entire code will look different once you have something that will even render stuff. Then you have the performance issues and all the "don't do this" in your code. (for instance, recreating functions, every loop).

Comment: and please make sure that you are indenting code properly.

Comment: @Torxed TBH the snake example you linked is far from good and does some questionable things...

Comment: Since this is most likely the first time you write this kind of code, my suggestion is to start lower. Start by making one single function that draws one single thing. Maybe the apple. Once you get that running correctly, build upon it. Don't rush it and try to write all the code at once.

Comment: So i thought about what you have and you are actually right, thank you guys for the help and for the suggestions! :D

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the objects don't appear because you never draw them by calling the `displaySnake` and `display_apple` functions. It also makes no sense to define these functions in the while loop again and again.

Here's a fixed version of the code. I've changed the movement code, so that the snake moves continually each frame. (It could still be improved, but I tried to keep it simple.)

```
import pygame, sys, random, time
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowWidth = 500
windowHeight = 500
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight), 0, 32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
color = (100, 100, 100)
snakeHead = [250, 250]
snakePosition = [[250, 250],[240, 250],[230, 250]]
applePosition = [random.randrange(1,50)*10,random.randrange(1,50)*10]
apple = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
apple.fill(green)
score = 0
speed = 10
# Define a velocity variable (a list or better a pygame.Vector2).
velocity = pygame.Vector2(speed, 0)


def collisionBoundarias(snakeHead):
    return snakeHead[0] >= 500 or snakeHead[0] < 0 or snakeHead[1] >= 500 or snakeHead[1] < 0


def collisionApple(applePosition, score):
    applePosition = [random.randrange(1,50)*10,random.randrange(1,50)*10]
    score += 1
    return applePosition, score


def displaySnake(snakePosition):
    for position in snakePosition:
        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, red, pygame.Rect(position[0], position[1], 10, 10))


def display_apple(windowSurface, applePosition, apple):
    windowSurface.blit(apple, (applePosition[0], applePosition[1]))


while True:
    # Event handling.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Replace `type` with `key`.
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                velocity.x = speed
                velocity.y = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                velocity.x = -speed
                velocity.y = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                velocity.x = 0
                velocity.y = -speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                velocity.x = 0
                velocity.y = speed

    # Game logic.
    snakeHead[0] += velocity.x  # Update the x-position every frame.
    snakeHead[1] += velocity.y  # Update the y-position every frame.
    snakePosition.insert(0, snakeHead)
    snakePosition.pop()

    if snakeHead == applePosition:
        applePosition, score = collisionApple(applePosition, score)
        snakePosition.insert(0, snakeHead)

    # Drawing.
    windowSurface.fill(color)
    displaySnake(snakePosition)
    display_apple(windowSurface, applePosition, apple)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(20)
```